# How to make Foam animation ? (insulation foam)

Tags: animation

How to make insulation foam animation in blender ?
At first i must show spraying of foam - then it gets bigger/grows in size: like in this video
[https://yandex.kz/video/preview?filmId=1056555290207049751&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D93NW2LdKzoM&text=Напыляемый%20пенополиуретановый%20утеплитель%20Polynor%20%28Полинор%29&path=sharelink&rdrnd=60954](https://yandex.kz/video/preview?filmId=1056555290207049751&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D93NW2LdKzoM&text=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20Polynor%20%28%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%29&path=sharelink&rdrnd=60954)   =  0:30 - 0:45 ?

Edited: or like here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSJh1Q-YdgE

Comment: and you did try what...!?

Comment: Hi :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck? This isn't a place to ask for full tutorials.

Comment: Actually i have no idea how to start....I thought maybe you know some looklike tutorials to copy from. I  just stuck at the beginning,dont knowing how to even start :(